# Azure Search Suggesters and Scoring Profiles

Tags: azure, search, scoring, azure-cognitive-search

Does anyone have experience with Azure Search Suggesters and Scoring Profiles? If you add a custom scoring profile to and index and set it as the default, will a suggester on that index use it? If not, what really is a suggester?

Answer (score 0):

Scoring profiles are not supported in the Azure Search Suggestions API. Please vote for this feature on [Azure Search User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search) page to help us prioritize.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone coming to this question....I wanted to use Fuzzy Search via a Suggester, in conjunction with a simple Linear Magnitude Scoring Profile. As @Yahnoosh stated, it appears that this does not work (even in 2020). I worked-around this by adding a numeric field to the index called "SearchPriority", which I set when I ingest documents. I then add this field to the Order By clause when executing the Fuzzy search.